# Resizing view to fill remaining space between UIToolbar and keyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a view which I would like to fill up the entire screen between a UIToolbar at the top and the keyboard at the bottom. I am listening for `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` messages to detect when the keyboard appears and using the following to adjust the view:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)notification {

    NSDictionary* userInfo = [notification userInfo];

    CGSize keyboardSize = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{

        subview.frame = CGRectMake(subview.frame.origin.x, subview.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width - 40, self.view.frame.size.height - 62 - keyboardSize.height - 20); 
    }];
}
```

This works fine in portrait mode but in landscape the view is all over the place. I have tried switching the width/height when the device is in landscape mode to no avail.

I know this is basic stuff but I've always struggled to understand how to adjust a view correctly for landscape mode.

Comment: have you set the autoresizeMask for the subview ?

Comment: I've tried with and without, still not working in landscape mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use  `CGSize screenSize=[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;`

Then replace,

```
subview.frame = CGRectMake(subview.frame.origin.x,
subview.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width - 40,
self.view.frame.size.height - 62 - keyboardSize.height - 20);
```

with this line:

```
subview.frame = CGRectMake(0,
subview.frame.origin.y, screenSize.width, screenSize.height - subview.frame.origin.y
- keyboardSize.height - 20);
```

I just tried and it worked on both directions, hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the hint but it doesn't work for me. The view disappears off the top left of the screen when rotating to landscape. I've tried with autoresizeMask set to none and flexible width/height.

Comment: Hi dude, let me understand your problem: is it when showing the keyboard after moving to landscape? Or when moving to landscape after the keyboard is visible?

Comment: Moving to landscape after the keyboard is visible.

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer was for solving the problem when the view was already in landscape.

If your problem is that when moving to landscape your view layout is not alright for you, then register for the following notification:

> UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification

Then, in the receiver method have something like this:

```
 - (void)orientationDidChange:(NSNotification*)notification { 
    CGSize screenSize=[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size; 
    CGSize keyboardSize =[myKeyboard frame].size;

        subview.frame = CGRectMake(0, subview.frame.origin.y,
        screenSize.width, screenSize.height - subview.frame.origin.y -
        keyboardSize.height - 20); 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem still exists either way. keyboardWillShow: is called after rotating the device and even when showing the keyboard when in landscape mode it still moves the view off screen.